# setParameter() is not setting the parameter supplied in java program with HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

Below is my code

```
String query="select w.statusCode,w.updateTime,s.statusCodeValue from WebsiteAvailability w,StatusCodes s where w.statusCode=s.statusCode and w.url=:sel";
String selUrl="www.google.com";
list=session.createQuery(query).setParameter("sel",selUrl).list();
```

The problem is in my HQL query in 'where' condition w.url=? it is taking.I checked it in server log and it is taking ? instead of selUrl value.Please help me.Here I am using hibernate so I used entities,properties instead of tables,column names.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you enplane more..
I am not able to understand..

Comment: ? is a placeholder which would be replaced by hibernate at runtime. Maybe you should explain your question more.

Comment: here after running my code ? is not replaced by the selUrl parameter which I have supplied.For example If I give                       String selUrl="http://www.google.com" then while running the code ? should be replaced by selUrl string right? But it is taking ? itself.This is my problem

Comment: Are you looking at the generated SQL? In the sql logs, you won't usually see the actual parameters value, but only their placeholders. To see which parameters are actually being passed, activate the 'org.hibernate.type' log in your logging library (ex. log4j) at "TRACE" level. Be warned that this generate a *lot* of logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not contain any error. It should work. Other way for passing parameter is like :

```
String query="select w.statusCode,w.updateTime,s.statusCodeValue from WebsiteAvailability w,StatusCodes s where w.statusCode=s.statusCode and w.url= ?";
String selUrl="www.google.com";
list=session.createQuery(query).setString(0,selUrl).list();
```